# Double count query in the same table - Group By

Tags: sql

My original syntax:

```
select count (*) as Total, description
from  ADSAccount
group by Description
```

Results:

```
Total   Description
--------------------
 20     CloudRoom
100     User
200     Cloud
800     AD
```

I'm trying to add a count separation of the "AD" accounts.

I need to split count 800 AD accounts with the following where clause:  where SAMAccountName like 'DOM%' and description =  'AD'

Tried the following but its not working:

```
select count (*) as total, description 
from ADSAccount 
left join 
    (select count (*) as DOM 
     from ADSAccount 
     where SAMAccountName like 'DOM%' 
       and description = 'AD')
group by Description
```

Expected Result
Results:

```
Total   Description
--------------------
 20     CloudRoom
100     User
200     Cloud
700     AD
100     AD-DOM
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please add sample input and output data.

Comment: Please give expected result

Comment: @ParthM.Dave  expected result:
Total   Description
--------------------
 20     CloudRoom
100     User
200     Cloud
700    AD
100    AD - DOM

Comment: please update your question here some confusion

Comment: Updated expected results, is this sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use `case when` if your SQL doesn't support `if` statement

```
with main as (

select
case when SAMAccountName like 'DOM%' and description = 'AD' then 'DOM'
 else description end as new_description
from ADSAccount
)
select 
new_description as description,
count(*) as total
from main
group by new_description
```

```
with main as (

select
if(SAMAccountName like 'DOM%' and description = 'AD','DOM',description) as new_description
from ADSAccount
)
select 
new_description as description,
count(*) as total
from main
group by new_description
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the "case when " worked exactly as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select count (*) as total
,case when SAMAccountName like 'DOM%' and description = 'AD' then 'DOM'
 else description end as description1
from ADSAccount 
group by description1
```

Comment: Does calculated column alias work in group by? I guess it's specific to database.

Comment: Hence my “Try something like…”

Comment: @vendettamit Please don’t edit someone else’s answer. If you disagree (or have what you think is a better alternative) then add your own answer

Comment: @NickW Thanks for the reply, unfortunately an error occured: Invalid column name 'description1' .

Comment: @Tseep Just replace column alias with your case expression in group by clause.

Comment: @NickW That's exactly why I edited the answer to fix the error not to change the answer.

Comment: @vendettamit as the questioner did not tag their question with a specific DBMS my answer was not wrong as it works as written with many DBMSs - so you weren’t correcting an error, you were giving an alternative answer

Comment: That was a suggested edit. You can always revert the suggestions as you already did. No offense taken.